# Velocity of touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a simple physics game in cocos2d and want to launch a particle on swipe a the speed of the swipe. To get the velocity I need to take two touches and determine the (difference in position)/(difference in timestamp). My problem is that I can't get two touches. I tried a few methods but none of them are working out.

I tried storing the first touch

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITouch *firstTouch;

...

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    [self setFirstTouch:touch];
    NSLog(@"first touch time 1: %f", self.firstTouch.timestamp);
}


-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    NSLog(@"touch ended");
    NSLog(@"first touch time 2: %f", self.firstTouch.timestamp);
    NSLog(@"end of touch time: %f", touch.timestamp);
}
```

but this gives me a difference in timestamps of 0 every time. It seems to replace the firstTouch with the most recent touch

Am I doing something wrong with pointers that this is replaced?

Perhaps I can take the last two touches from ccTouchesMoved?

Comment: Why dont you save the timestamp instead of firstTouch in `ccTouchesBegan` method and then compare? That should give the correct one.

Comment: I'd need to save the timestamp and the location. Seems to make more intuitive sense to keep them combined. Plus, why can't I just save the first UITouch?

Comment: Sergio has already answered your question. Please check it.

Comment: @ACB I'm having trouble getting it to work. When I do (give me a few hours please, at least), I'll check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A far easier way of doing what you are trying to do is adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your `[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView` and then use the `velocityInView` property of the gesture recognizer.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)] autorelease];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and then:

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    ... recognizer.velocity...
}
```

If you want do follow your approach based on `ccTouches...`, it seems to me that possibly there is a misunderstanding about a swipe gesture, in that it is not made of 2 touches: it is just one touch that has a begin, some moves, and an end. So you need to track the movement of your finger in `ccTouchesMoved:`; then in touchesEnded determine whether it is a horizontal or vertical swipe, the direction, and send out the bullet.

Hope either of these suggestions may help.

Comment: I can't figure out where to enable the gesture recognizer. If I put it in the same location I enabled touch (`self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`), Property 'gestureRecognizer' is not found.

Comment: fine, that code was meant to use a property, but the declaration was not provided with it. I simplified it so to not use any property and just instantiate and add the gesture recognizer to the view. I usually put that code in my app delegate, but I think it will work anywhere else.

Comment: Ah that seems obvious. Thanks. However, there are two glaring problems: this only registers when I Swipe to the right, and recognizer has no property called "direction."

Comment: not sure I understand your point. in any case, I added some more bits to my answer.

Comment: `Property 'velocity' not found on object of type 'UISwipeGestureRecognizer *'`

Comment: you are right, I am sorry about the mismatch... the real thing is `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `velocityInView`... I will edit my answer....

Comment: Worked, thank you for the help! Only thing now: This disables all my ccTouches methods. Is there a way to trigger when the swipe is done?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by triggering when the swipe is done. maybe what you want is `gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO` when you create it... this should let the touches be also handled by cocos2d...

Comment: I don't found [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView

Comment: @AnandK: you are likely using a newer Cocos2D version. Inspect CCDirector.h file to check how the attribute is called...